# Need a regexp to extract a Sub String of a String

Tags: java, regex

I have a string, The string looks like :

```
abc/axs/abc/def/gh/ij/kl/mn/src/main/resources/xx.xml
```

I want to get the content after `n` occurrences and before `m` occurrences of the character `/`.
For instance, from the string above, I want:

```
mn/src/main
```

Please suggest some solution for this.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Could you also specify example values of `m` and `n` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex you require is this :

```
(?:.*?\/){7}(.*?)(.*)(?:\/.*?){2}$
```

a generic regex:

```
(?:.*?\/){n}(.*?)(.*)(?:\/.*?){m}$
```

substitute 7 and 2 with n and m and you will get your result

demo here:

http://regex101.com/r/bW2yF3

Comment: Thanks for the information .. the tool was very useful.. Any good tutorial or webpage that has useful information to learn regular expressions ?

Comment: I am using ((?:[^/]*/){5}) to get the content until first 5 occurrences of / .. But my matches specifies that it doesn't match.. Am i missing anything here.

Comment: Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("((?:[^/]*/{5})").matcher(fileModified);
if (matcher.matches()) {
String str = matcher.group(1); system.out.println(str); }

Comment: the only thing you need to do is to escape the `/` forward slashes like this `\/`

Comment: I am getting invalid escape sequence when i am trying to escape / with   \/ in JAVA

Comment: you need to escape it with two back slashes in java like this `\\/`

Comment: Tried with this as well, When we escape with 2 backslashes, the matcher.match() is returning false for the string abc/axs/abc/def/gh/ij/kl/mn/src/main/resources/xx.xml

Comment: the regex I have provided will work buddy, sorry but I dont have enough experience in java. thats all the help I could provide.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()`.

```
String path = "abc/axs/abc/def/gh/ij/kl/mn/src/main/resources/xx.xml"
String [] tokens = path.split("/");
```

Now just print it:

```
for (int i = n; i < m; i++){
    System.out.print(tokens[i] + (i != m - 1 ? "/" : ""));
}
```

Comment: You will need to remove the last `/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use regex:

```
String s = "abc/axs/abc/def/gh/ij/kl/mn/src/main/resources/xx.xml";
int n = 7;
int m = 10;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:[^/]*/){" + n + "}((?:[^/]*/){" + (m - n - 1) + "}[^/]*)/.*");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
if (matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```